# Replacing placeholders in HTML template with textbox values

Tags: html, vb.net

I've created an HTML template with placeholders, like #Name#, #Address#, #City#, etc.

How can I access the file and replace the placeholders with TextBox values from the form? Then, once the replacements have been made, how can I save the file with a new name.

I'm trying StreamReader and StreamWriter at the moment, but not having much success. Here's what I have so far. Im getting this exception upon button click:

System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "C:\test.html" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ReadTextFile()

    Dim TempText As String
    Dim TextPath = "C:\test.html"
    TempText = ReadTextFile(TextPath)
    TempText = TempText.Replace("#Name#", TextBox1.Text)

    WebBrowser1.Navigate("C:\test.html")
End Sub

Public Function ReadTextFile()
    Dim TempString As String
    Dim TextFileName As String = "C:\test.html"
    Dim StreamToDisplay As System.IO.StreamReader
    StreamToDisplay = New System.IO.StreamReader(TextFileName)
    TempString = StreamToDisplay.ReadToEnd
    StreamToDisplay.Close()
    Return TempString
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: `File.ReadAllText`, `String.Replace`, `File.WriteAllText`.

Comment: I've edited my original post with the code I have now, but I'm getting an exception now.

Comment: If only there was some way that we could know the details of the exception.  Also, you have four lines in that `ReadTextFile` method that could be replaced with one if you call `File.ReadAllText`.  Finally, there's no code to save anything after editing there.

Comment: Ok, I've implemented the ReadAll, Replace, and WriteAll directly from MSDN. Cant get the String.Replace working, but the WriteAll works with a text file. When I change the path to the HTML file, it locks up immediately. In reference to the saving, I wasnt sure where to start on that since I dont want to overwrite the template file. I just want to replace the placeholders temporarily to be able to save it as a different file name.

Comment: If you have edited your code then you should edit your question to reflect that.  We can't see what you're doing wrong if we can't see what you're doing.  Note that you should add to your existing question rather than replace what's there.  That way, people reading comments that refer to something from the original will not be confused.

Comment: I'm not sure what I was thinking when I edited the original post. It was late and I apologize. I'm going to do some more research on this and report back. It doesn't seem to be too complicated of a procedure or am I being too optimistic?

Comment: You could do it all in one line of code, although I'd probably break it into three at least and maybe more if you wanted to put each `Replace` call on its own line.